# Is there a way to hide single bookmarks or bookmark folders in Google Chrome (or Chromium)?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, chromium

In Opera I can choose to hide bookmarks and bookmark folders from the bookmark bar, is this also possible with Google Chrome or Chromium?

As a workaround I put all the bookmarks I don't want to see in a separate folder within a folder that's on the bookmark bar.

The "Other Bookmarks" folder is **not** what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's quite counterproductive to downvote questions without leaving an explaination.

Comment: The whole point of having the bookmark bar folder is to show the bookmarks on that bar. For those you dont want to see on that bar(a.k.a. hide), there is Other Bookmarks. Isn't that right?

Comment: In Opera, bookmarks are not arranged like Chrome. There is only one place for storing bookmarks. You can choose which one to show on bookmark bar. So, if I compare the both methods, when you choose to hide a bookmark on Opera, in Chrome, you're just moving it from Bookmark Bar folder to Other Bookmarks folder. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `CTRL + SHIFT + B`  This will show and hide the bookmarks bar.,. is that what you want?

Comment: @Bibhas If you want to remove a bookmark from the bar but not from the bookmarks, then there doesn't seem to be a way to do that. Also, it doesn't seem to allow the user to put their own bookmarks(from the bookmark manager?) in the bookmark bar. Does it sound like I'm doing something wrong with my approach to the book bar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chrome's Bookmark Manager allows you to create folders either in the Bookmark Toolbar folder (which gets shown on the Bookmarks Toolbar) or in the Other Bookmarks folder. You can't create a folder anywhere else.

If you don't want to use the Other Bookmarks folder, there isn't any other way except for the method that you use currently.

Comment: Yeah, I started this question after giving up on finding a solution. Just wanted to make sure it's not possible. Would have been nice to be able to hide the "Other Bookmarks" folder, but still be able to access it via the bookmark manager. Guess I'll stick to my approach. Unless someone can come up with a great hack in the next few days, the bounty is all yours. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to see the bookmarked link? A common feature in most, if not all, browsers today is the ability to autocomplete the URL based on the contents in you  history and/or bookmarks.

I believe it will also recognize any metadata you enter during creation, e.g. subject tags.

Caveat: Firefox user, so I do not have an in-depth knowledge of Opera's features.

Comment: They do show up (in Chromium and also in Opera), but I cannot remember all those bookmarks that I like to have available in the bookmark list.

Comment: Of course its hard to remember hundreds of bookmarks :) But perhaps they can reside at a somewhat more obscure location, where you only go for the ones you can't readily remember?

Answer (score 1):

For FireFox, I have developed this:
[StealthMarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stealthmarks/)

It creates a folder in the bookmarks where you can put all your private bookmarks. Then, you can show/hide this folder whenever you want.
Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

To hide bookmarks simply right click on any bookmark on the bookmark bar > Open Bookmark Manager > pick any bookmark you want to hide and move to other bookmarks.

This is for chrome may not work on other browsers.